# Can't get required to work in select tab

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that has various select input options and I just can't get the required instruction to work.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or missing? I've also included the top of my page where the html is declared in case that offers any clues. 
(I am using jquery and ajax to post form). the Thanks.

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zLlONqQxEw) which works but for some reason on my page it doesn't

The Jquery

```
       <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(e){
$('#gauge').empty();
  e.preventDefault();


//Post form 
var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
    $.post('insert.php', formdata,
           function(data){
  //Reset Form
$('#myform')[0].reset();  
fetchRowCount();
    });

    return false;
 });
});
//Fetch data from server
function fetchRowCount() {
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'server2.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
$("#rows").html(data.rows);
$("#min").html(data.min);
$("#max").html(data.max);
$("#mean").html(data.total);
$("#last").html(data.last_entry);

//Show gage once json is receved from server

           var gage = new JustGage({
          id: "gauge",
          value: data.total,
          min: data.min,
          max: data.max,
          title: "Sample Data"

       });
  $("#gauge").fadeIn(slow);

                    }

     });

}
</script>

The html form

<form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" form="" method="post">

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text" placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>

<select id="utility_type" name="utility_type" class="form-control input-lg" required/>
 <option value="" >Energy Type</option>
      <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
      <option value="Gas">Gas</option>
      <option value="Gas &amp; Electric Combo">Gas &amp; Electric Combo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submitButtonId" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you create a bootply so we can see it in action

Comment: Post all of your code.. form, submit button, etc..

Answer (score 2):

The required attribute means that the input type must be filled before you're submitting your form. you don't use a form tag here, therefore the required attribute is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <form method="POST">
  <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text" placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

required attribute will only work with submit button

Replace:

```
<button id="submitButtonId" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
```

With

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButtonId" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I've attached the entire which works as expected in Bootply but not on my page.

Comment: In your code there is no submit button, you are using button tag instead of submit

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. I am submitting the form with jquery post. I wonder of that is causing the problem?

Comment: Please see my updated code to show the jquery I am using.